# Change SMSC on dual-sim phone

Tags: cyanogenmod, sms, 6.0-marshmallow, dual-sim

I've got a Wileyfox Swift with two SIM cards, running CyanogenMod 13. I can only send SMS from one card/carrier, not from the other.

My guess is that is has to do with the [Short Message service center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_service_center) setting.

Changing the SMSC as [described on the CyanogenMod wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/SMSC_Updates) only allows me to set one SMSC - but I think I would have to set both.

Is that correct, and how can I set the 2nd SMSC number?

Others have similar problems: [ilogik@reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/26v06z/setting_smsc_on_a_dual_sim_moto_g/)

Answer (score 1):

Came across this when I had the same issue. A bit late for the OP, but another thing to look out for.

If you go in to:
Settings> Sim Cards> Preferred SIM for SMS messages> Select SIM card> Ask every time

Comment: LineageOS 14.1 does not offer the "ask every time" option :/